# General representation of ODE solution

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems

I was wondering if for an ODE system of form
$$
\dot{x}(t) = f(x(t), u(t), t)\\
x(t_0) = x_0,
$$

the general solution
$$
x(t) = x_0 + \int_{t_0}^{t} f(x(\tau), u(\tau), \tau) \,d\tau
$$
is valid for all cases, assuming integrability of $f(x(\tau), u(\tau), \tau)$ on $[t_0, t_f]$.

Comment: Not the way you wrote it, but $x(t)=x_0+\int_{t_0}^t f(x(τ),u(τ),τ)dτ\;$ will do it. The upper limit is not $t_f$ but $t$, the variable on which $x$ depends. Note that this is now an integral equation, as the unknown $x(t)$ is also inside the integrand, so probably you should not call this equation the "solution".

Comment: Indeed, I should have stated the inital condition $x(t_0) = x_0$ and the upper limit was wrong. I'm going to edit the original post.

Comment: The problem is that this type of writing down the solution is not explicit. The function $x(t)$ is still part of the integrand. So it is not really a solution to the ODE it is just another way of writing the ODE.